# FullCalendar Row Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, fullcalendar

I've been trying to fix this 'lenghty' row right below the 9PM on my full calendar but I can't seem to figure out how. Anyone can help, perhaps?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried looking into the documentations for FullCalendar? Did it help?

Comment: Yes, I did actually but nothing seemed to click. I must've missed something out but I'm all out of ideas.

Comment: No worries, I have upvoted your question.

Comment: I'd guess it's because the height of your calendar detail area is shorter than the area you've allocated for the calendar overall. Can we see your calendar config code please? Also please take a look at https://fullcalendar.io/docs/sizing